# Intermittent file saving / deletion issue with Ubuntu-hosted Samba share

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ubuntu, samba

In our office we have a Ubuntu Linux 14.04 server on which we develop our PHP websites. The folder in which they all live is shared via Samba, with the following config:

```
[Sites]
comment = PHP Sites
path = /var/www
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
browsable = yes
create mask = 0664
directory mask = 0775
read only = no
force user = www-data
force group = www-data
```

Not the most secure but it's internal only and works for us - well, most of the time....

This share is accessed by a combination of machines on our network - some Macs (10.10.3), some Windows (7) and a couple of Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). I've tried to set up netatalk/afp for the Macs but that's a different question.

Various colleagues on the Win and OS X machines have reported intermittent problems either copying files to certain folders, or with saving PSD files when working in Photoshop. On some occasions, when the file saving errors occurs the files are actually DELETED from the share.

I myself get the occasional popup in Coda telling me I can't save a file, even when I've worked on and saved it repeatedly in the time leading up to the error.

I've checked all the permissions and as far as I can work out, they are correct. We had a Linux server a few years ago and I don't remember having these problems. I know Adobe don't recommend working on PSDs over a network share but we never had this problem when using a Mac as our PHP dev host - and this problem extends beyond just Photoshop.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.